# How to use UILocalNotification with certain distance?

Tags: iphone, distance, uilocalnotification

I am trying to alert user with a notification that if he reaches with a radius say 100m of a certain annotation (i created them) he should receive a notification.

Can any direct me in d right way cause m not able fto find anythng :/.

Thanx alot guys

Comment: Also is there a way to invoke local notifications using distance and not the fireDate property.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get local notifications to trigger on anything except date.  Anything else would require a background task, I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` does not have any other means to display them other the the fireDate method.

If you want to tell the user that he is coming close to a specific GPS point you will need to let you app receive location updates when it is in the background. 
You can do this by adding `Required background modes` mode to the info plist and set it to `App registers for location updates`.
Now your app will keep receiving updates in background, this will only work on iPhone 3GS and up.

Then just schedule the `UILocalNotification`  with a fireDate set as `[NSDate date]` and it will fire immediately.

Comment: thnx for d post i was applying ur logic only bt d thng is wen i fireDate set as [NSDate date] its nt responding to right time ssome hr behind ex: fire date = 2011-09-14 10:11:02 +0000 when correct time is 15:41:02

Comment: Can't make head not tails of your comment, please try to use correct english.